# How can twins be born months apart?

Tags: reproduction, twins

How can twins be born months apart? What is the science behind it?

Comment: Well once the womb is open... But just google it and you'll see that it's very rare but it happens that there are a few days of interval !

Comment: In vitro fertilization creates twin embryos.  One is implanted & carried to term, the other is frozen, and later thawed and implanted.